# iOs (CoreLocation) - locationManager:didUpdateLocations: not working as expected

Tags: ios, core-location

I wrote a simple iPhone app that retrieves location information and simply display them. 
I want to increment the `distanceTraveled` variable every time the position changes. 
My problem is that in the method `locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations`, `locations.count` is always equal to one. I thought it would add an element to the array every time the method is called, but it seems not like that...

I am running the application in the simulator (I don't have a device now).

This is my code:

```
// BIDViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface BIDViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *startingPoint;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latitudeLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *longitudeLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *horizontalAccuracyLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *altitudeLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *verticalAccuracyLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *distanceTraveledLabel;

@end



// BIDViewController.m :

#import "BIDViewController.h"

@interface BIDViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic)CLLocation *currentLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic)CLLocation *lastLocation;
@property CLLocationDistance distanceTraveled;

@end

@implementation BIDViewController

@synthesize latitudeLabel;
@synthesize locationManager;
@synthesize longitudeLabel;
@synthesize startingPoint;
@synthesize altitudeLabel;
@synthesize distanceTraveledLabel;
@synthesize horizontalAccuracyLabel;
@synthesize verticalAccuracyLabel;
@synthesize currentLocation;
@synthesize lastLocation;
@synthesize distanceTraveled;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    //locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0f;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    if (startingPoint == nil) {
        startingPoint = [locations lastObject];
        NSLog(@"first time -- locations.count = %d", locations.count);
        distanceTraveled = 0;
        distanceTraveledLabel.text = @"0m";
    }
    else if (locations.count > 1) {
        NSLog(@"into the else if -- locations.count = %d", locations.count);
        lastLocation = locations[locations.count -2];
        distanceTraveled = distanceTraveled + [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:lastLocation];
        distanceTraveledLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%gm", distanceTraveled];
    }

    NSLog(@"locations.count = %d", locations.count);

    currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

    latitudeLabel.text =
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g\u00B0", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    longitudeLabel.text =
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g\u00B0", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    horizontalAccuracyLabel.text =
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%gm", currentLocation.horizontalAccuracy];
   verticalAccuracyLabel.text =
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%gm", currentLocation.verticalAccuracy];
    altitudeLabel.text =
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%gm", currentLocation.altitude];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSString *errorString = [[NSString alloc] init];

    switch (error.code) {
        case kCLErrorLocationUnknown:
            errorString = @"Location unknown";
            break;

        case kCLErrorDenied:
            errorString = @"Access denied";
            break;

        case kCLErrorNetwork:
            errorString = @"No network coverage";
            break;

        case kCLErrorDeferredAccuracyTooLow:
            errorString = @"Accuracy is too low to display";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error getting location"
                                                    message:errorString
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

@end
```

This is what the logger looks like:

```
2012-11-21 11:28:34.882 WhereAmI[652:11c03] first time -- locations.count = 1
2012-11-21 11:28:34.897 WhereAmI[652:11c03] locations.count = 1
2012-11-21 11:28:35.835 WhereAmI[652:11c03] locations.count = 1
2012-11-21 11:28:36.835 WhereAmI[652:11c03] locations.count = 1
2012-11-21 11:28:37.836 WhereAmI[652:11c03] locations.count = 1
2012-11-21 11:28:38.836 WhereAmI[652:11c03] locations.count = 1
2012-11-21 11:28:39.837 WhereAmI[652:11c03] locations.count = 1
2012-11-21 11:28:40.837 WhereAmI[652:11c03] locations.count = 1
2012-11-21 11:28:41.838 WhereAmI[652:11c03] locations.count = 1
2012-11-21 11:28:42.839 WhereAmI[652:11c03] locations.count = 1
```

and so on...

Any advice? Thanks everyone and, as always, sorry for the bad english!

Comment: Why are you expecting more than one location? Usually one is fine. Here is what doc says **An array of CLLocation objects containing the location data. This array always contains at least one object representing the current location. If update events were deferred or if multiple events arrived before they could be delivered, the array may contain additional entries. The objects in the array are organized in the order in which they occurred. Therefore, the most recent location update is at the end of the array.** Of course sim doens't help if oyu simulate just one position.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; i didn't say it in the question but i was simulating location changing through the simulator (changing the value of the simulated location while running my app in the simulator)... so i thought it would trigger the delegate and add another entry in the array with the new location...

Comment: @aveschini I am also facing same problem did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm sorry... i'm not working on that project anymore... I don't remember if i found a solution and I don't have the source code anymore. So, sorry but i can't help you!

Answer (score 2):

Simulator will not return more than one location since it uses the location of your computer, so you get the precision of your Wi-Fi and that's it unless you change to another Wi-Fi network somewhere else while running it should never return a more accuracy/different location.

If you're testing on an actual device that moves, or if the device first gives you the cell tower accuracy, then Wi-Fi, then GPS accuracy you will receive more than one location in the array.

Hope this clears it up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; i didn't say it in the question but i was simulating location changing through the simulator (changing the value of the simulated location while running my app in the simulator)... so i thought it would trigger the delegate and add another entry in the array with the new location...

Comment: How exactly are you going about triggering location changes manually in the simulator?

Comment: With the focus on the simulator I go to: Debug -> Position -> Custom position. I am using the italian version of the simulator, so it could named different.

Comment: I've noticed some strange behavior when I change the location of the simulator, using the menu like you did.  Seems that the new location does not take effect until I stop and restart the simulator.

Comment: Sounds like there may be issues running these kinds of tests in Simulator.