# CLLocation manager not calling Update locations delegate frequently

Tags: iphone, ios6, cllocationmanager

I am using cllocation manager for getting user current location in my application delegate class.Some thing like this:

```
-(void) getUserCurrentLocation
{
    destinationForProgressView = .25;
    if(![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        UIAlertView *enableGpsInYourDevice = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Go to settings and enable location services" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [enableGpsInYourDevice show];
    }

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    // This is the most important property to set for the manager. It ultimately determines how the manager will
    // attempt to acquire location and thus, the amount of power that will be consumed.
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    // When "tracking" the user, the distance filter can be used to control the frequency with which location measurements
    // are delivered by the manager. If the change in distance is less than the filter, a location will not be delivered.
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    // Once configured, the location manager must be "started".
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

I am conforming to location protocol and implementing its delegate method:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];

    latitude =  newLocation.coordinate.latitude;

    longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    NSLog(@"lattitude from appDelegate   is %.8f", [[locations lastObject] coordinate].latitude);

    NSLog(@"longitude from appDelegate is %.8f", [[locations lastObject] coordinate].longitude);
}
```

Where lattitude and longitude are in .h:
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationDegrees latitude;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationDegrees longitude;

In this way I am able to get current location but it does not get updated if I change lat and long rapidly from simulator debugger.

Then in my view controller I am simple accessing latitude and longitude properties like this:

```
-(void) getLocationCoordinates
{
    self.destinationForProgressView = .25;

    //[DELEGATE getUserCurrentLocation];**NOTE**

    latitude = [DELEGATE latitude];
    longitude = [DELEGATE longitude];

    if (latitude && longitude) {
        NSString *prepareMessagebody = nil;
        memberID = [USERDATASINGLETON getMemberID];
        prepareMessagebody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latitude is %.8f\n Longitude is %.8f\n Member-ID is %@",latitude, longitude, memberID];
        NSLog(@"test %@", prepareMessagebody);

        NSArray *reciepients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"stack@over.com", nil];

        NSArray *passingobject = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:reciepients, prepareMessagebody, nil];

        [self performSelector:@selector(showMailPickerwithObject:)
                   withObject:passingobject
                   afterDelay:1];
    }
    else{
        [self showalertIfLocationServicesDisabled];
    }
}
```

when I again make a call to delegate method see NOTE and commented code //[DELEGATE getUserCurrentLocation]; I am able to get frequently updated locations.
**Should I make a call again to delegate class for updating location, should not my delegate update location** 
`(@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationDegrees latitude and
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationDegrees longitude;)` and thus in to my view controller.
Please suggest?

Comment: didnt understand what do you want in your question...

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be simulator issue as outlined [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491594/ios-corelocation-locationmanagerdidupdatelocations-not-working-as-expected) are you able to test it on an actual device?